# NSSortDescriptor Not Working to Organize TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, sorting

I am working on sorting my TableView cells and it is not working for some reason. I had an earlier revision of the exact same code and the exact same PLIST but I could have sworn it worked for several months. Now it refuses to sort.

Sorting Code inside the numberOfRowsInSection method:

```
NSString *date = [self.months objectAtIndex:sectionNumber];
NSDictionary *monthData = [self.sportDictionary objectForKey:date];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: nil ascending: YES];
NSArray *days = (NSArray *)[[monthData allKeys]sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor2]];

for(int x = 0; x < [days count]; x++)
{
    NSLog(@"Day: %@", [days objectAtIndex:x]);
}
```

When I look at the output of the NSLog, it is not right. Getting 15, 22, 29, 3, 8

The part of the PList that it's sorting is as shown:

```
<dict>
<key>1 September 2012</key>
<dict>
    <key>3</key>
    <array>
        <string>Georgia Tech (Orange Effect)</string>
        <string>8:00 PM </string>
        <string>Home</string>
    </array>
    <key>8</key>
    <array>
        <string>Austin Peay (White Effect)</string>
        <string>1:30 PM</string>
        <string>Home</string>
    </array>
    <key>15</key>
    <array>
        <string>Pittsburgh (White Effect)</string>
        <string>12:00 PM</string>
        <string>Away</string>
    </array>
    <key>22</key>
    <array>
        <string>Bowling Green</string>
        <string>TBA</string>
        <string>Home</string>
    </array>
    <key>29</key>
    <array>
        <string>Cincinnati</string>
        <string>TBA</string>
        <string>Away</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: VT football fan huh? Go Jackets!(GT Alumni here) Your date is formatted as a string, so it doesn't understand that 3<22 because the sorting is comparing the 2(the first character in 22) vs the 3.

Comment: ahhh... I understand. Is there anyway I can get the key to be read as an integer? What would be a good way to fix it? Thanks!  P.S. Yea haha I am a VT Alumni :D

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to take the NSDates that you already have, extract the day components as NSNumbers or ints and then sort and continue with what you already have. [Here](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/476-How-to-extract-current-year-month-and-day-from-an-NSDate-with-NSCalendar-NSDateComponents-and-NSDateFormatter) is something that might help you on extracting the day component of the NSDate.